# Problemas con tabs y formulario bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, formularios, bootstrap-4, tab

Tengo un problema creando un formulario en boostrap, el cual en parte del formulario debe ir dos tabs con cada uno campos alineados como en esta foto de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan, es un formulario el cual esta dentro de un "card" y divididos en dos columnas, esto mismo lo quiero añadir, pero dentro de dos tabs, los cuales serian la continuacion del formulario, pero al realizar lo mismo, queda todo mal configurado y se corren los campos...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo esta quedando asi para esa seccion de los "tabs" que queda desalineado:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-bordered" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="comunicacion-tab-b1" data-toggle="tab" href="#comunicacion-b1" role="tab" aria-controls="comunicacion-b1" aria-selected="false">
                    <span class="d-block d-sm-none"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></span>
                    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Comunicación</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="corporativo-tab-b1" data-toggle="tab" href="#corporativo-b1" role="tab" aria-controls="corporativo-b1" aria-selected="true">
                    <span class="d-block d-sm-none"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Corporativo</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane show active" id="comunicacion-b1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="comunicacion-tab-b1">
                <div class="row">

                    <!-- Sub Columna 1 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="direccion1" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-form-label">Direccion 1</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                                <input id="direccion1" name="direccion1" type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Sub Columna 1 -->

                    <!-- Sub Columna 2 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="direccion2" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-form-label">Direccion 2</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                                <input id="direccion2" name="direccion2" type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Sub Columna 2 -->

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="corporativo-b1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="corporativo-tab-b1">

                <!-- Sub Columna 1 -->
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                </div>
                <!-- Sub Columna 1 -->

                <!-- Sub Columna 2 -->
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                </div>
                <!-- Sub Columna 2 -->

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Espero se entienda y me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Con el código que has suministrado tu problema no se puede reproducir. Lo he copiado y pegado [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/feoz2a8w/) tal cual y no me pasa lo que a ti.

Comment: Asegúrate que no tienes un `div` mal cerrado en algún lado, o que no has sobreescrito alguna clase de bootstrap. O si tienes CSS extra que no hayas añadido a tu pregunta.

Comment: @masterguru, fijate que si agrandas la seccion donde muestra los campos, si ocurre el problema que te indico, los input pasan a quedar al lado de los tabs

Comment: @Oriel Pues tienes razon... si le quitas el `<div class="row">` que aparece después de `<div class="card-body">` ya no ocurre.

Comment: Era justo el error que comentaba @Benito-B, tenia un `div` mal cerrado y por eso el error, muchas gracias!